# React: How to get response from server which uses data from http web request

Tags: reactjs

I need to get response from server on my frontend.
On frontend I don't have route that leads to server.
I have only route on server /api/v1/smsreceive/receive on which I send http post request with body data from external application.
Now I need to get response on my frontend.
Code looks like this:

export function smsReceive(req, res){
 Some function to save data to database with data from my req
}

So, now, because this function from my server doesn't have route on frontend. What do I have to do to get res on my frontend. Maybe I need route on frontend that leads to server with function which gets data from my previously writen smsReceive function?

If anyone have an idea please share with me. Thanks

Comment: You cannot access a server from the frontend without the server-address, how is the browser supposed to find the server otherwise? Just save the server address as a constant in your react app

Comment: Could you please elaborate and be more concrete. I don't understand what exactly your issue is.

Comment: if you are wanting to hide your server url so that no one can find it, generally the way you would do that is by having a proxy web server that does session / authentication and then it would talk to your actual server that has the DB connection. Regardless of this the UI will need a server origin to make requests to.

Answer (score 2):

On my understanding, you need to make a request to your server to get the data.

1st: Go to your server and create a route which will provide the data you want.

2nd: Enable CORS - it will let you make cross domain request

3rd: Go to your frontend and use native fetch. It will be something like:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://your.server.app:3000/route')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({data}));
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>);
  }

}
```

Comment: Just as a fair warning, you may get downvotes for using `axios` as its introducing a library that the OP is not using (or hasn't said hes using). Instead you should probably just use `fetch` as its native :)

Comment: You should also check the response has a 200 code 

Comment: Trigger for everything to work is web request from external application. So now i need something like setInterval to track success response from server on my frontend. Is that good idea?

Comment: No. You will have it here:

.then(data => this.setState({data}));

if you dont want to use state, you can replace this.setState by your code, like:

.then(data => {
  ...
  console.log(data)
})

Comment: Read more about Promises and you will understand what I am doing at this point.